# iOS - open photo from photo album in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, uidocumentinteraction, camera-roll

I would like to let users browse photos in their photo albums, tap the action button, and share/open selected photos in my app. Some apps (like Viber and WeChat) provide a custom view to handle this. This is the WeChat screen:

[image]

What is the name of this feature and which class do I have to use to achieve this behavior?

Comment: If I get you properly you need this : http://www.imore.com/best-apps-support-sharing--action-extensions-ios-8. This is only avaliable in iOS 8. Check here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html. Let me know I am right or not.

Comment: Ok start learning it all the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do check for share option in the ioS extensions

1. [app extensions](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/)
2. [extension programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/)

EDIT:

Removed 3 & 4 links, which are not working. thanks to Daniel.

Share extension can be found inside the Extension programming guide(2nd link > App Extension Types > Share)

Comment: I think you don't get question. He dont want image picker. He want that Default photo app share image with his application.

Comment: Add this link in your answer : http://bryan.io/post/97658826431/what-we-learned-building-the-tumblr-ios-share This is very good experience sharing from Tumble developer team member.

Comment: Links 3 and 4 are broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIImagePickerController for the purpose.
 Find Class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html)
 Here is a [Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: My goal is not letting users take photos. It's instead opening their own photos from within the system photo app into my app through a custom screen like WeChat and Viber do.

Comment: You mean you have to access the Photos app? If that is the case follow this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html)